# Can I pass props between two slots inside one Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a hard time grasping slots to be honest. Here's my issue:
I've got one component called Projects.vue where I'm using Buefy to create tables and I'm wrapping the tables inside a template tag as such:

```
<b-table :data="projects" hoverable>
  <template v-slot="project">
   <b-table-column field="id" label="ID" width="40" numeric>{{ project.row.id }}</b-table-column>
   <b-table-column field="name" label="Name">{{ project.row.name }}</b-table-column>
   <b-table-column field="owner" label="Owner">{{ project.row.owner }}.    </b-table-column>
   <b-table-column label="Action">
    <b-button
      outlined
      class="is-small is-primary"
      @click="(row) => showUsersInProject(project.row)">Project details
    </b-button>
   </b-table-column>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

This simply renders a table with details about a project such as name of project, owner, id and a button "Project Details".  Upon clicking the button `Project Details`, I render another table to show all the users inside that project as such:

```
<b-table :data="usersInProject" hoverable>
<template v-slot="user">
  <b-table-column field="id" label="Id" width="40" numeric>{{ user.row.id }}</b-table-column>
  <b-table-column field="firstname" label="First Name">{{ user.row.firstname }}</b-table-column>
  <b-table-column field="lastname" label="Last Name">{{ user.row.lastname }}</b-table-column>
  <b-table-column field="email" label="Email">{{ user.row.email }}</b-table-column>
  <b-table-column label="Action">
    <b-button 
    :disabled="deletedUsers.includes(user.row.id)"
    outlined class="is-small is-danger" 
    @click="deleteUserFromProject(user.row)">Delete user
    </b-button>
  </b-table-column>
</template>
</b-table>
```

My question is - how would I pass the `projects` props from the `project` template to the `user` template?  I need to get the `project.row.owner` from the first table to be displayed in the second table.

Answer (score 1):

You can expose data via scoped slots, inside your `Projects.vue` you need to create a slot like so:
`<slot :projects="projects"></slot>`.
 when doing this you later can expose the projects like so:

```
   <Projects>
            <template v-slot="{ projects }">
              any code you put here has access to projects data property (including user template)
            </template>
   </Projects>
```

Comment: Slot-scope is being deprecated, no?

Comment: the syntaxe is deprecated...
`v-slot` that unifies `slot` and `slot-scope` in a single directive syntax

Comment: changed it for the new syntax